# Is it possible to connect two monitors on a laptop, one through HDMI and the other through DisplayPort?

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport

For example the Alienware m17x offers 3 connections, HDMI, DisplayPort, and VGA. Is it possible to connect two independent external monitors, one through the DisplayPort and one through the HDMI port?

Comment: That's actually an interesting question. Have you tried it already? For my Intel GMA it doesn't work. It is a dual head GPU because it can connect to two screens (to the laptop display and the VGA or DVI port). For anything different you would need a triple/quad head GPU, two GPUs or at least the possibility to switch from the Laptop screen to one of the external connectors.

Comment: My current laptop only supports hdmi/vga. I'm looking to replace it with one that will support two digital outputs, hdmi, dvi, displayport, etc. I just can't find any reliable information on how well they will work together...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is yes so long as your drivers support it. It would certainly be possible if you were using a usb displayport adapter I'm just not sure whatever chipset your running would support different output to 3 connections (assuming you want to extend your desktop not just have it cloned on multiple screens)