# Can my laptop use 3 monitors?

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors

I have a Dell E6510 with a Nvidia NVS 3100M graphics card.  Can I plug in a monitor into my displayport and then another into my VGA port and utilize 3 monitors?

Comment: Have you tried it?  Here is a related question: http://superuser.com/questions/31607/is-it-possible-to-connect-two-monitors-on-a-laptop-one-through-hdmi-and-the-oth?rq=1

Comment: More importantly, what have you tried? Google?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer? Yes you can.

Long answer? Yes you can, but it may require an alternative solution to the windows standard. Try out DisplayFusion. Worked for me on several multi-display builds I've worked on in the past with stranger physical setups.